# How to remove specific message from queue on RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, amqp

Client publish 5 message in to queue(name is Q) with Rabbit MQ

Q

100 --first

101

102

103

104 -- last

I have a c# task that consumes all messages automatically when clients publish some messages.

Client can see on the UI which is consuming still or which is consumed.

Think that message("100") is consuming and Client want to remove message("103") at the same time.Is that possible?If it is possible how to solve it?

Comment: Can you please add some code to make it clearer? Most importantly the consumption task...

Comment: RabbitMQ doesn't allow you to "remove" a message. If you want to filter messages, you will have to write a filter service. This service just consumes everything from the queue, decide which message to keep and publish them into a different queue.